# Improve execution time for recursive md5sum check?

Tags: grep, find, hashsum

This recursive md5sum check for 40000 items of 11.8 GB takes 2 minutes:

```
ret=$(find "${target}"/ -name ".md5sum" -size +0 | while read aFile; do cd "${aFile%/*}"; md5sum -c ".md5sum"; done | grep -v "OK";)
```

Can any obvious speed improvements be made, that I have not noticed?

Comment: I think that maybe you're already hitting the limits of your IO subsystem. Simply reading 12 GB of data from disk in 2 minutes averages to 100 MB/s which would be what you can expect from a typical SATA harddisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

Unless you decide to forgo the check altogether if size+timestamp matches, there is little to optimize if the checksums actually match; the files will all be identical but to verify that, you actually have to read all of it and that just takes time.

You could reduce the number of `md5sum` calls to a single one by building a global MD5SUMS file that contains all the files. However, since the bottleneck will be disk I/O there will be not much difference in speed...

You can optimize a little if files are actually changed.

If file sizes change, you could record file sizes too and not have to check the md5sum, because a different size will automatically mean a changed md5sum.

Rather than whole file checksums, you could do chunk based ones so you can stop checking for differences in a given file if there already is a change early on. So instead of reading the entire file you only have to read up until the first changed chunk.

Comment: Oh, and I guess if the filesystem is on a software RAID-1 you could improve speeds by running 2 md5sum processes in parallel. Since mdadm-RAID1 only uses one disk per read request...